# C programming bi directional communication

Tags: c, unix, multiprocessing, ipc

I am trying to make something work here, I have c program where my parent process creates a pipe so he can listen for request from children processes. These children are created dynamically, it is never the same number. So far, I managed to send the requests to the parent through the pipe, and have it synchronized through mutex.

My problem is, this request need an answer provided to the child that made such request, and I can't use the same pipe since its one way, and all the other children will be using it (I already tried and it generates a serious issue)

The next thing I tried was making a pipe before the request on the child and passing the value of the descriptor in the request. Also failed, since the parent doesn't know those descriptors, which I found out after failing.

So now I am clueless in how to make that request response reach the child...
I am a beginner with C programming, so, all help is welcomed!

BTW: working in a Unix program, pure C programming

Comment: Have you tried passing a pipe descriptor to the parent process along the pipeline that the child is listening for a response on?

Comment: Also can we see some code

Comment: You could give each child process a pipe for input and a pipe for output, and the parent process would use the other ends. If you can use `stdin` and `stdout` for the pipes, the better. 
Sockets are another alternative. http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html is a good source of info. So are Richard Stevens books on UNIX programming.

Comment: @phyrrus Hi! yes, i did try that, and it doesnt work, at least not how i put it, wich was calling pipe(var[]) in child and pasint var[1] to the parent. The parent doesnt know the descriptor id :/

Comment: @PSkocik but arent sockets for tcp ip communication? can they be used locally as well?

Comment: Sockets can be used locally, yes. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Local-Socket-Example.html is an example of how.

Comment: You can bind a TCP socket to localhost or better yet, use UNIX sockets, which are always local.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pipes are uni-directional and using sockets seems painful for a little ipc thing.

I recommend you to use `socketpair()`. You can consider them as bi-directional pipes.

Here is an example where the parent sends a character to its child.Then child makes it uppercase and sends it back to the parent.(It is from [beej](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html#socketpair)'s tutorial)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sv[2]; /* the pair of socket descriptors */
    char buf; /* for data exchange between processes */

    if (socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sv) == -1) {
        perror("socketpair");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!fork()) {  /* child */
        read(sv[1], &buf, 1);
        printf("child: read '%c'\n", buf);
        buf = toupper(buf);  /* make it uppercase */
        write(sv[1], &buf, 1);
        printf("child: sent '%c'\n", buf);

    } else { /* parent */
        write(sv[0], "b", 1);
        printf("parent: sent 'b'\n");
        read(sv[0], &buf, 1);
        printf("parent: read '%c'\n", buf);
        wait(NULL); /* wait for child to die */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also you can easily use two pipes for your two directions.